# How to move search icon of search-bar at right side of search bar in ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4, searchbar

I'm Developing a Hybrid app using `ionic-4`. I have my simple search page and I want to move the search icon to the right side of the `ion-searchbar` component. I have tried this with different `CSS` rules but i didn't find any solution.

my ionic searchbar code is as below:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-searchbar showCancelButton="never"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share your code so far? also are you using cancel option? this may help for clarity

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Thanks for reply, I have updated my question. I'm using cancel option also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the search-bar component [does not have shadow dom enabled](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/searchbar/searchbar.tsx), you can manipulate the CSS of the inner components just fine. You just need to reset the `ion-icon` `left` CSS property and make sure you are doing this inside `global.scss`:

```css
ion-searchbar ion-icon {
  right: 16px !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

If you set `dir="rtl"` on the `html` tag inside `index.html`, you can see that ionic does this the same way when the icon needs to be flipped:

```
[dir=rtl].sc-ion-searchbar-md .searchbar-search-icon.sc-ion-searchbar-md {
  left: unset;
  right: unset;
  right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to alter the styling in page scss instead of global.scss?

Comment: How to programmatically switch rtl and ltr per component? What if I want to have 2 search fields in different languages?  It's stupid to expect rtl to be always at the application level.